# What effect has no close tags for HTML input field on browsers?

Tags: html, input, tags

I came across a production HTML page which has no close tag for one of the input fields.

This production system has been running for quite a while and targeting only IE6 browsers.

I would like to do a check with everyone here, as i am striving to give a good reason to raise a defect fix, are there any good supporting reasons for doing such?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the doctype of the page? That should validate with an HTML 4.01 doctype. However, it will NOT validate as XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Chin,

Most (if not all) browsers will imply the end tag for things like input, br, img and p which traditionally have been mis-coded.

Some parsers (specifically I know of iText to create PDF from HTML documents) require absolute perfect HTML, but you can use another tools such as jTidy to fix that on the fly.

Brian